# How to ensure complete data has been re-partitioned while re-partitioning with a successful completed Spark job?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, amazon-s3

My objective is to re-partition data from source and save it at the destination path. I intend to create only one S3 object per partition and I have achieved that using the following:

```
df.repartition("created_year", "created_month", "created_day").write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy( "created_year", "created_month", "created_day").parquet(dest_path)
```

I want to ensure that all the data has been transferred and I learned that re-partitioning might drop out the duplicates. So, I decided to check whether the distinct count of each of the source and destination should match. So, I did the following:

```
source_df.distinct().count() == destination.distinct().count()
```

This returns `False` indicating that the distinct count is different in source and destination, in those jobs that had all the tasks completed.

Is this the right way to check whether the complete data was re-partitioned and saved? What is the better/right way?

The source and destination are the two different buckets on Amazon S3.

The possible MVC is:

```
def count_distinct(src_path, spark):
    try:
        df = spark.read.parquet(f'{src_path}')
        distinct_count = df.distinct().count()
        print(distinct_count)
        return distinct_count
    except:
        log_failed_bucket(src_path)
        return None

def compare_distinct(spark, bucket_name):
    src_path = form_path_string(bucket_name)
    original_distinct_count = count_distinct(src_path, spark)
    dest_path = form_path_string(bucket_name, repartitioned_data=True)
    final_distinct_count = count_distinct(dest_path, spark)
    return original_distinct_count == final_distinct_count
```

Comment: `repartition` does not remove duplicates. You must have some other parts of the code not shown that affect the counts

Comment: To get single file per partition you to change code a bit: `.repartition(1, "created_year", "created_month", "created_day")`

Comment: I just call these two functions - that is it. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've given all columns in `partitionBy` it's not possible to remove duplicates while writing, and providing all columns in `partitionBy` is also `not possible`.

In-case of any `nulls or empty` value for any of the partition columns, it'll be under `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` folder respectively to your partition column.

> `` If multiple paths are read using spark.read.format().load(), then you should provide `basePath` option (there's a chance of missing paths if it's formed dynamically), else you could directly load `basePath` and follow sanity approach mentioned below ``

1. You can check the count/distinct after grouping based on partition columns between source and target dataset.
2. The total count can be checked from basePath with sourcePath.
3. Distinct value count combination check of partition columns between source and target.